# Launch a new instance when a threshold of HTTP requests is exceeded

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-cloudwatch

I'm trying to use EC2 and CloudWatch to start up a new instance after I hit a certain number of HTTP requests per minute. Is this possible?

Comment: are you aware of auto scaling? are you using an ELB?

Comment: Yes I am, I'm trying to configure the auto-scaling for our site. We are using an ELB and that's exactly where I needed to find the information I was looking for. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not out of the box.  You can create auto scaling rules on EC2 instance metrics, but request/minute aren't tracked.  You have CPU, Disk I/O, and Network metrics available.

You could base it on network activity, or you could create a custom Cloudwatch metric and feed it information from your instance.